# JNA passing structure containing pointer to structure(s) and pointer to primitive

Tags: java, jna

I am using JNA and finding it very straight-forward for retrieving data from a native library, but struggling to understand how to to do it the other way round, i.e. passing structured data to a native method.

I'll use a small example from part of the library I'm trying to invoke.

The native library typedefs are as follows:

```
typedef struct CreateInfo {
    int count;                    // Number of queue infos
    const QueueInfo* queues;      // Zero-or-more queue info structures
} CreateInfo;

typedef struct QueueInfo {
    int count;                    // Number of queue priorities
    const float* priorities;      // 'array' of queue priorities
} QueueInfo;
```

So we have a `CreateInfo` that refers to a number of `QueueInfo` each of which contains a list of floating-point values.

A naive JNA implementation of these structure could be as follows (field order, constructors, etc omitted for brevity):

```
public class CreateInfo extends Structure {
    public int count;
    public QueueInfo.ByReference queues;
}

public QueueInfo extends Structure {
    int count;
    public Pointer priorities;
}
```

So:

1. The JAN mappings are (intentionally) naive but are they really stupid?  If so what are the logical types?
2. If I *already* have an array of `QueueInfo` can I simply set the pointer to the first element of that array?  Or do I **have** to allocate an array using `Structure::toArray`? The structures have no constructor other than the default, should they have?
3. I have the queue priorities float array but how do I set the pointer?  Should it actually be a pointer or something else?  A float[]?

I can find lots of questions on SO and the interwebs in general for *receiving* structures from a native library, but relatively few for *passing* structured data. And the examples I've found all use different approaches for the same problem that seem very complex for what should be pretty simple (?) so I'm at a lost for the 'correct' approach.

I suspect I'm not asking the right questions which probably means I'm missing something fundamental about JNA.

Hopefully some kind soul can point out what is wrong with the naive JNA code above and how it could be populated with data on the Java side.

Comment: So it looks like the 'standard' answer to question #2 is that one **must** instantiate an array of structures using `Structure::toArray`, e.g. `final QueueInfo[] queues = (QueueInfo[]) new QueueInfo().toArray(size); for(int n = 0; n < size; ++n) { ... }`

Comment: Partial answer to #1 is that a 'pointer to array structure' field should be `Structure.ByReference`.  Modified the JNA accordingly.

Comment: #1: Depends on your definition of stupid.  #2: Using the `Structure.toArray()` method is more convenient because you don't have to `read()` each structure from native memory. You can also use a `Pointer` and instantiate the structure from the appropriate offset using a pointer constructor. 
 #3: `Pointer` is generally a good mapping. What you'll end up with is a native-allocated buffer that you can use `Pointer.getFloatArray()` to retrieve the values.

Comment: @DanielWiddis Not sure what you mean by "retrieve the values"?  I don't need to retrieve anything, I already have the data in the Java code, I just need to pass it to the native library as a field in a structure.  Or am I missing your point?  Perhaps you could provide a quick pseudo-code snippet of what you mean?

Comment: Sorry, was thinking you were reading C allocated memory. The opposite pattern is generally `Memory buffer = new Memory(bytes)` where `bytes` contains enough space for your data.  `Memory` is a subclass of `Pointer` so you have access to the `write()` methods, in this case, `buffer.write(long offset, float[] buf, int index, int length)`.  Set the `Pointer` in your structure to `buffer` and it should work.

Comment: You might find [this example](https://www.eshayne.com/jnaex/index.html?example=10) helpful, just change `double` to `float`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1 - JNA mappings**

Mappings are designed to directly relate Java-side types to the corresponding native side types.  When the memory required for these mappings is well known, JNA works very well.  Unfortunately, when the amount of native memory to be mapped is variable, that requires a bit of work to allocate and map the required native memory. There are a few ways to go about doing this, with varying levels of abstraction/control.

**2 - already have QueueInfo[] (part 1)**

With the way you've defined `QueueInfo` in your question, it's not helpful.  You've only defined a Java-side class but the `Pointer` class implies a native memory pointer.  You should modify your class to extend `Structure` and use `public` on your `count` field.  Note that instantiating this structure will only allocate native memory for the `int` and the `Pointer`.  The memory for the array itself will need to be allocated separately.

**3 - allocate float array**

As I mentioned in the comments, [one way of doing this](https://www.eshayne.com/jnaex/index.html?example=8) is to allocate native memory for the float array:

```
Memory buffer = new Memory(count * Native.getNativeSize(Float.TYPE));
```

Then assuming you have `float[] buf` defined you can copy this into the native memory using

```
buffer.write(0L, buf, 0, count);
```

You can then just use `buffer` as the `priorities` field of your `QueueInfo` instance.

**2 - already have QueueInfo[] (part 2)**

Now to the question, you can't just set the pointer to the first element unless you know you have a contiguous C-side array.  Your choices are using `Structure::toArray` to allocate the memory (and then populating each element) or separately creating an array of (contiguous) pointers and copying over the `Pointer` value from your separately allocated structures.    For the `toArray` variant, you don't need a pointer constructor if you directly set the values in the generated array, but the pointer constructor can make copying (from one native memory block to the other) easier.

**Summary**

Option 1: instantiate separate `QueueInfo` structures using the `Pointer.write()` method for the float array.  It might be helpful to create a constructor which takes the `float[]` as an argument and sets the `count` and allocates and sets `priorities` variable as described above.   Then, create an array of `Pointer`s for the `CreateInfo` structure and copy over each element's reference pointer.

Option 2: create an array of structures using `Structure::toArray` to allocate the native memory; then iterate over this structure and directly create the `QueueInfo` structures at the appropriate index.

Comment: Thanks for explanation (and your other answers on the related question), I think I *get* this now!  I'll answer both questions assuming I sort this out.  Incidentally your answer to #2 was due to my mistake, of course `QueueInfo` was extending a JNA structure, I just messed up the cut-and-paste.

Comment: As an aside: is there a way on SO to link two questions I've posted that I now know are essentially the same?

Comment: If you edit your original question to include a link to the other SO post, it should show up on the right-hand margin under "Related". However, having answered your other question, they're not quite the same. This one deals primarily with an array of ByValue Structures which contain a pointer to an array of primitives elsewhere in memory, while the other one deals with a ByReference contiguous buffer of Structures. And the answers are subtly different.